# I'm creating a constructed language. Does this type of conlang exist?

Tags: typology, creoles

Is there a type of conlang which tries to combine and simplify French and English?
(Few word examples)

1. I- Mi
2. You- Vu
3. We- Nu
4. This- Di
5. That- Do
6. Who- Ve
7. What- Ku
8. No- No

Note:- This language is not just French and English combined. It also makes up similar sounding or entirely different words.

Comment: I know I've heard of a language like this, but I can't remember what it was called. Obviously, that doesn't mean you can't make your own.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going for an 'ancient but evolving', 'simplistic but not too simplistic' language spoken by humans in an earth-like environment but with different geography and history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something similar already exists. Languages of this type are called somewhat despectively *Euroclones* in the conlang community and the field of such languages is pretty well trotted out, though most designers prefer English-Spanish blends with simpler phonology over English-French blends. Euroclones are often marketed as International Auxiliary Languages by their respective proponents.

For the personal pronouns, [Ido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ido_language) looks like a good match.